# List Title changed name? How to change it back?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, title

When creating a custom or new list in SharePoint 2013 and then you go in to add an item, it shows "Last Name" instead of "Title" like it use to say.  Is there anyway to change this back?  If so, how would I do it?

See examples below. Figure 1 is how it should look but figure 2 is what it is coming up as.

I know I can change it back to Title manually, but I want it to change it back to title automatically when it is creating the list.  It should say "Title" not "Last Name"..  I have searched google but haven't found a solution yet.

Figure 1 (how it should look):
[image: This is how it should look]

Figure 2 (how it looks):
[image: Title column changed to Last Name automatically]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the site column for Title (part of the underlying Item content type) got renamed to "Last Name".

This can happen, for example, if you go to Site Settings -> Site Content Types -> Item (under List Content Types) -> Title (under columns) -> Edit Site Column

Unfortunately, changing the Title field's display name back to "Title" is notoriously difficult through the interface, since SharePoint insists that the Title field name is reserved (and isn't bright enough to realize that it's the Title field that you're trying to fix).

If you have access to remote into the servers, you can use PowerShell and the SharePoint server object model to rename the field.

For example:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$siteurl = "URL of top-level site"
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
$web=$site.OpenWeb()
$field=$web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title")
$field.Title = "Title"
$field.Update()
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

Otherwise, you can do the same thing using JavaScript. While viewing a site within the affected site collection, open the F12 developer tools JavaScript console and execute the following script to rename the Title:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext("/serverRelativeUrlOfRootWeb");
var field = context.get_web().get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
field.set_title("Title");
field.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        alert("Field renamed successfully.");
    },
    function(sender,args){ 
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Replace `/serverRelativeUrlOfRootWeb` with the server-relative URL of the root site of the site collection where you need the field renamed.

Comment: Thank you Thriggle, that was perfect!  I used the F12 Developer tool opened up the JavaScript console, changed the relative url and it worked!